# Refreshing activity or listview after updating database

Tags: android, listview, android-database

So I have my custom ArrayAdapter with a getView method defined like this

```java
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        int orderId = getItem(position).getId();
        int menuId = getItem(position).getMenuId();
        int userId = getItem(position).getUserId();
        String status = getItem(position).getStatus();

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);

        TextView idView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.order_id);
        TextView nameView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        TextView userIdView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_id);
        TextView statusView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.status_view);
        ImageButton cancelButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.order_canceled);
        ImageButton orderDoneButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.order_done);
        cancelButton.setTag(orderId);
        orderDoneButton.setTag(orderId);

        if(status.equals("done"))
            orderDoneButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.checkbox_on_background);
        else {
            orderDoneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    orderRequest.getGenericRequest().setUri("/" + v.getTag() + "?status=done");
                    orderRequest.put();
//                ((ImageButton)v).setImageResource(android.R.drawable.checkbox_on_background);

                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    // TODO cheating but it works
//                Intent intent = activity.getIntent();
//                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
//                activity.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
```

- And my problem is that, when I call it as this and I click on OrderDoneButton, my list view is not updating itself, even if I am calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` and I see the database is updated, my question is why?
- The second question is in this method there is commented out '`Intent`' which works in the way I want, but I am not sure if this is a good way to doing that, any suggestions?

Comment: you need to tell us what is `getItem()` and where is your data, and you can call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in your activity or fragment, below your *database updated* method

Comment: @IqbalRizky getItem() is method build in ArrayAdapter which allows you get item from array which is passed  to adapter. My data are in database(?) and displayed in list view. As you can see in code snippet I am updating database from adapter, because of that I want to update my view/activity from adapter after I click on list view item.

Answer (score 0):

here some explanation what i usualy did

setup view with adapter

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> listPName = new ArrayList<>();
private void showBluetoothPrinters() {
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listPName) {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NotNull ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView tv = view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            tv.setPadding(padding * 3, 0, padding * 3, 0);
            return view;
        }
    };
    lvPrinter.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

then call notifyDataSetChanged() after update some data

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> mPairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
                if (mPairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                    for (BluetoothDevice mDevice : mPairedDevices) {
                        listPName.add(mDevice.getName());
                    }
                }
                if (arrayAdapter != null){
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
```

dont know if this is what you expect

i add some of snippet  call notifydatasetchage in adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VH holder, int position) {
    int amount = mListData.get(position);
    holder.tvAmount.setText(String.valueOf(amount));
    holder.tvText.setText(decimalFormat.format(amount));

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (mListener != null){
            mListener.onAmountTapped(amount);
        }
        tempSelected = position;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    });
    if (position == tempSelected){
        holder.containerView.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rp_shadow_select));
    } else {
        holder.containerView.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rp_shadow));
    }
}
```

Comment: No it is not. Cause you calling updating database from activity and in this place you are creating and holding ArrayAdapter, so that allows you to call arrayadapter.notifyDataSetChanged() and I believe it works. But I create CustomArrayAdapter where inside it I am updating my database and from that place I want to notify my view/activity to update itself.

Comment: try greenrobot event bus`https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus` if you want to notify other class